# Only null values in received properties of HttpPost, posting array, using action with IEnumerable parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc action that takes the following parameter

```
public ActionResult SetParameters(IEnumerable<KeyValue> parameters)
{
}
```

KeyValue is declared as:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Firebug shows that this post variables is sent:

```
parameters[0][key]     foo
parameters[0][value]   bar
```

Why do I not get populated members of KeyValue, both key and value are null.
The number of parameters however, is correct.

Comment: Can you show your view. To post back to `IEnumerable<KeyValue> parameters` your controls would need names such as `name=[0].key"` and `name=[0].value"`

Comment: Can there be rarest possibility that it is not working IEnumrable and work with IColletion take a look http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: The posting is done with javascript which generates an array like [{key: "foo", value: "bar"}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only magic in sending list of objects to Action is how to set intup's name. The ASP.NET MVC `ModelBinder` does not understand expressions like `parameters[0][key]`. 
It understands only `parameters[0].key` but in ajax submits nested objects will be sent in the `parameters[0][key]` format.

```
var parameters = [
        { key: '1', value: 'foo' },
        { key: '2', color: 'baz' },
        { key: '3', color: 'bar' }
    ];      

    parameters = JSON.stringify({ 'parameters': parameters});

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: parameters,
        success: function () {          
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
        }
    });
```